# Generate Guid on database but only when not set in entity

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, guid

I have a case where I need to add a Guid Property that is NOT the primary key, and that could be shared with several objects in the table.

What I'd like to do is:

- Generate the Guid on the database when I don't give it a value
- Set a Guid (instead of generating it) when I have its value

Both of this would be done on Insert only, Updates won't touch these values.

What I have tried:

- Add the [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] attribute: only works when I don't need to set the Guid manually
- Add the [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)] attribute: doesn't work when I don't set the Guid manually

I've seen quite a lot about this topic, and the closest thing would be this article:
http://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2012/09/23/calculated-columns-in-entity-framework-code-first-migrations.aspx

But we don't (and won't) use Migration in our project, so that doesn't seem fit.

or this SO question, but that would mean generating Guids in .Net (which doesn't seem to be very clean, at least in my opinion): [EF, Code First - How to set a custom Guid identity value on insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13743483/ef-code-first-how-to-set-a-custom-guid-identity-value-on-insert)

Is there a way to generate the Guid Database side, AND set it when I need to in EF Code first?

If not, what would be a good alternative? Is it really a bad idea to generate Guids on the .Net side? (I could go with that if nothing else is possible)

Comment: you can edit your migration and set default value newid(), and mark it as databsegeneratedoption.identity

Comment: @HadiHassan actually we don't (and won't) use migration in this project... Do you know another way to set the "newid()" thing though?

Comment: I think you can only do this with an insert trigger that sets the guid in case a null value was supplied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that you are using MS-SQL , then you can do the following

**To use the execute command**

```
public class YourDbContext: DbContext
{
     public YourDbContext():base("ConnectionString")
     {              
            if (Database.Exists())
            {                   
                Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("if object_id('CT_DefaultGuid') is null alter table YourTable add constraint CT_DefaultGuid default newid() for YourColumn");
            }
     }
}
```

**To set the Id from .Net**, you can do the following

- Create a Base Entity contains Id property
- In the constructor you check if the Id is empty then initialize it
- Let all the entities you have to inherits from this class

Your base class should look like

```
public class BaseEntity
{
     public BaseEntity()
     {
          if(Id==Guid.Empty)
               Id = Guid.NewGuid();
     }

     public Guid Id{get;set;}
}
```

**To use the migration for existing database**

- from PMC => `Enable-migrations`
- from PMC => `Add-Migration "FirstRun"`
- open the generated migration file and make sure to  empty the `Up` and `Down` methods ( this will not apply any changes on the database)
- Add the corresponding alter column fluent code using `Sql("")` method in the Up method
- from PMC => `Update-Database -Script` , to make sure that only sql statement generated is the alter table statement
- from PMC => once you are sure that the desired statement is the only appearing in the SQL script , then apply : `Update-Database`.

Your class should like this

```
public class FirstRun : DbMigration
{    public override void Up()
     {
        Sql("alter table YourTable add constraint CT_DefaultGuid default newid() for YourColumn");
     }
}
```

I recommend the last approach, it will be executed once, and you can add changes later to your database.

Hope this will help you

Comment: Thanks, you assumed right and this does help, could you explain a little more please? Also does this mean this check would be done at each context creation? (There can be quite a lot of this)

Comment: yes it will occur upon each context creation, that is why I proposed in the comments to use the migration, migration will add great potential to your code, for example to create views and to seed data.

Comment: this code with execute totally on first time and will execute the if statement late, if you don't want to make the round trip to the db,  you can encapsulate this code by a value stored in the appsettings and update it after first run, this will prevent  the code from execution later

Comment: Yep migration could have been a good thing, I agree with you, but the project is late and I know we won't investigate this feature since none of us is familiar with it.

Comment: This seems to be a good solution, I'll give it a try tomorrow (for now I'm generating these guids on the .Net side)

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer, definitely gives solutions to the problem!