# Define a field as autoincrement in EF5 migration

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm creating a table using a EF migration such as:

```
this.CreateTable("Message",
            c => new
            {
                Id = c.Long(nullable: false, identity: true, defaultValue: 0),
                Subject = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 64),
                Body = c.String(nullable: false, isMaxLength: true)
            })
            .PrimaryKey(c => c.Id)
            .Index(c => c.Id, unique: true);
```

How can I define the Id field to be auto_increment? I'm pretty sure it has to be possible, but im just struggling to find out...

Thanks.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12012736/entity-framework-code-first-using-guid-as-identity-with-another-identity-column

Comment: there's not another way to do it than using anotations? The other option that I can see is just using raw sql to create the column with identity but...it feels like there should be a way to do it by code.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, it seems that setting the property "identity: true" in field should be enough but for some reason the field is not defined as IDENTITY(1, 1).

Found a workaround in this post:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/33db16ac-e166-455f-a47b-1e5fe0557979/

And it worked for me like this:

```
Id = new ColumnModel(PrimitiveTypeKind.Int64) { IsNullable = false, IsIdentity = true },
```

Now its defining the column as IDENTITY(1, 1)

Answer (score 1):

If you do want to automatically generate it in code, you could skip the annotation on the Id field and do something like below.

```
public abstract class AbstractContext : DbContext {

      /// <summary>
      /// Custom processing when saving entities in changetracker
      /// </summary>
      /// <returns></returns>
      public override int SaveChanges()
      {
          // recommended to explicitly set New Guid for appropriate entities
          foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries<ModelBase>().Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Added) ) {

              // only generate if property isn't identity...
              Type t = entry.Entity.GetType();
              var info = t.GetProperty("Id").GetCustomAttributes(
                  typeof(DatabaseGeneratedAttribute), true).Cast<DatabaseGeneratedAttribute>().Single();

              if (info.DatabaseGeneratedOption != DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity) {
                  entry.Entity.Id = Guid.NewGuid(); // now we make it
              }
          }
          return base.SaveChanges();
      }

    }
```

For more information check [**Working with Entity Keys**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd283139.aspx)

*I got this from the link Which I showed above comment.*

I hope this will help to you.

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain myself, I meant that there should be a way to set the column as IDENTITY(1,1) by using migration code. Anyway, i found a solution that works! see my own answer below.