# Entity Framework Code First Using One column as Primary Key and another as Auto Increment Column

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a class named **Sale**

```
public class Sale
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string TrNo { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<SaleDetail> SaleDetails { get; set; }
}
```

And in the database, I want the `Id` as the `Auto Increment` column and the `TrNo` as the `Primary Key` column.

Please tell me how to do this using EF5 code first.

Thanks.

Comment: Something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12012736/entity-framework-code-first-using-guid-as-identity-with-another-identity-column

Comment: Why do you need Id column, if TrackingNumber is a good, natural identifier?

Comment: @Seevali do you resolved this ? i has the same issue please provide solution

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14612813/entity-framework-code-first-using-one-column-as-primary-key-and-another-as-auto/14613001#14613001) of @IronMan84 correct. But it didn't work for me. I slightly modified it to apply my another condition. And it worked. I did nothing else.

This is my solution.

```
public class Sale
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(TypeName = "varchar"), MaxLength(50)]
    public string TrNo { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<SaleDetail> SaleDetails { get; set; }
}
```

Unfortunately I can't make the answer of @IronMan84 as the correct one as it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 48):

You can also do this with Data Annotations:

```
public class Sale
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Key]
    public string TrNo { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<SaleDetail> SaleDetails { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But not working. It created me a table that only the `Id` column as the `PK` and `AutoIncrement` column

Comment: No chance. Same as before.

Answer (score 17):

I believe you can do this using Fluent API

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Sale>().Property(a => a.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Sale>().Property(a => a.TrNo).HasKey(b => b.TrNo);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But not working. It created me a table that only the `Id` column as the `PK` and `AutoIncrement` column

Answer (score 5):

This helped me. Hope this helps anyone else that still looking around

```
public class Sale
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]//switch on autogenerated
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Key]//set as Primary key
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]// switch off autogenerated PK
        public string TrNo { get; set; }

        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public int CustomerID { get; set; }

        public ObservableCollection<SaleDetail> SaleDetails { get; set; }
}
```