# C# mvc How to set AutoIncrement on

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nextval

Hi I am trying to create a new customer record. The primary id customerid is autoincremental column.

When I try to insert a new record I get this error :

**Message=Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Customer' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.**

This is the same code I am using :

```
NewCustomer.Name= user.Name;
NewCustomer.Address= user.Address;
NewCustomer.Phone = user.Phone;
NewCustomer.Email= user.Email;

db.Customers.Add(NewCustomer);
db.SaveChanges();
```

I read somewhere that I have to set  autoincrement on, but I am using entity framework and not any direct sql.
Can some one please help how I could turn on autoincrement so I could insert records?

Comment: Are you using SQL Server as your database?

Comment: Does entity framework know that the column is auto-increment?  How did you create your models and your database?  If you generated the models against the database before it was auto-increment and then later changed the database then you'd have to update the models, for example.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3188194/c-entity-framework-auto-increment-problem, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14612813/entity-framework-code-first-using-one-column-as-primary-key-and-another-as-auto