# How can specify ROWGUIDCOL property to Guid type column in code first or with ColumnBuilder?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Consider this migration code:

```
       CreateTable(
            "dbo.Document",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    Doc = c.String(),
                    RowGuid = c.Guid(nullable: false),
                    Person_Id = c.Int(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Person", t => t.Person_Id)
            .Index(t => t.Person_Id);
```

i want the `RowGuid` be `ROWGUIDCOL`, and be defined like this (SQL):

```
 [RowGuid] [UNIQUEIDENTIFIER] not null RowGuidCol Unique default newid()
```

What is the equivalent code in `EntityFramework/CodeFirst` ? What is the solution?

Thanks.

Comment: anybody has a solution yet to this one? I am blocked on this very issue.

Comment: btw .. what rowguidcol does ?

Comment: @vishalsharma, go to the following link and scroll down to read Clifford Dibble's answer: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d4e763fd-13ee-40a2-9ace-443df609fbdf/rowguidcol Essentially it just tags the column so that it can be referenced generically via $ROWGUID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not appear that the ROWGUIDCOL property can be set directly via Entity Framework, but it *might* be possible to inject the property into the generate SQL by making "creative" ;-) use of the storeType parameter (assuming storeType truly allows you to override the default datatype). Starting with the code from the original question, try something like the following:

```
 CreateTable(
            "dbo.Document",
            c => new
                {
                    RowGuid = c.Guid(nullable: false, identity: true,  
                                     defaultValueSql: "newid()",
                                     storeType: "UNIQUEIDENTIFIER ROWGUIDCOL"),
                    Person_Id = c.Int()
                })
            .Index(t => t.RowGuid, true);
```

Unfortunately, I do not have a way to test this, but given that the following SQL works, I think it is worth a shot:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Test1
(
    Col1 INT NOT NULL,
    Col2 UNIQUEIDENTIFIER ROWGUIDCOL NOT NULL UNIQUE DEFAULT NEWID()
)
```

The "UNIQUE" requirement is accomplished via a Unique Index created by the second parameter being "true" in the Index() method.

Please note that there might be some issue using "identity: true" in the Guid() method if the table already has a column marked with IDENTITY. I found this related question which addresses that situation: [Entity Framework Code First Using Guid as Identity with another Identity Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12012736/entity-framework-code-first-using-guid-as-identity-with-another-identity-column)

Comment: This doesn't work. It produces "Column, parameter, or variable #4: Cannot find data type UNIQUEIDENTIFIER ROWGUIDCOL."

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Odd. Is it possible that newer versions of EF do validation that wasn't there in the version that the O.P. was using? This question and answer are 3 years old, so possibly something has changed? What version are you using, just for reference?

Comment: Possibly, yes. I am using EF6

Comment: yeah, it works. but in net core you should write "type" not "storetype"

Answer (score 5):

I imagine you want this for a table with a `FILESTREAM` column. Hinting EF with an EntityTypeConfiguration makes it generate correct scripts and doesn't need you to manually edit it (EF Core 2.2).

Taking this sample entity:

```
public class FileEntity
{
    public Guid FileGuid { get; private set; }
    public byte[] Document { get; private set; }
}
```

And this configuration:

```
public class FileEntityConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<FileEntity>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<FileEntity> builder)
    {
        builder
            .Property(m => m.Document)
            .HasColumnType("VARBINARY(MAX) FILESTREAM");

        builder
            .Property(m => m.FileGuid)
            .HasColumnType("UNIQUEIDENTIFIER ROWGUIDCOL")
            .IsRequired();

        builder
            .HasAlternateKey(m => m.FileGuid);
    }
}
```

EF generates a correct migration script:

```
FileGuid = table.Column<Guid>(type: "UNIQUEIDENTIFIER ROWGUIDCOL", nullable: false),
Document = table.Column<byte[]>(type: "VARBINARY(MAX) FILESTREAM", nullable: true)
```

Comment: FileStream is not enabled in my database and I run the query programmatically through SQLCommand to enable FileStream after database is deployed. I have added the changes on OnModelCreating to add FileStream attributes as per your post. But, in my case, my table which has FileStream attributes does not get created, which I think is because I dont have FileStream enabled at the time database is deployed. How can I resolve my issue?

Comment: @user1579234, in that case, I would add an initial migration script that runs after the DB is created to enable FileStream.

Answer (score 2):

After some research and asking around, I don't think it's possible.  The way I got around it in my code is to get a new GUID when I new up an object:

```
    public class MyPOCO {
           public MyPOCO() { 
                RowGuid = Guid.NewGuid();
           }
      //.....
   }
```

In this way, I'm always generating a new GUID when I insert a new row into the table.  I miss using ROWGUIDCOL but EF does make my life simple.

Comment: This can be kind of a bad idea due to the guid fragmentation issue. You want it to use NEWSEQUENTIALID() in the mssql server, which it will do if you set it as identity ([DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]). Fortunately you can just use a migration: Sql("ALTER TABLE mytable ALTER COLUMN mycolumn ADD ROWGUIDCOL");