# Entity Framework, retrieve saved value that is not always computed

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an Entity Framework conundrum I am having problem with.

I have a GUID property I need to pass in on a save, that maps to a field that will be altered by a trigger if it is an empty GUID.

If I use DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed, EF does not pass the value in (but would retrieve it). If I do not use it, the value is not retrieved and I need to refetch the entity to get to the property.

Ideally I guess I want a version of Computed that also allows value to be set, or a DatabaseGeneratedOption.AlwaysRetrieve, or some such. Is there any other way of marking a property to always retrieve its value from the database after an insert?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't so much an EF problem but more a DB provider issue.

With most databases you either have it auto-generate a GUID identifier or you don't, there is no in-between. The alternative is to write a custom trigger which detects whether you have passed an ID from the client and if not generate one server-side.

Ultimately that would mean leaving your ID field in EF set to `DatabaseGeneratedOption.None` so you can pass values from the client.

Comment: it is a trigger that is generating the GUID in this case. The problem to some degree is with EF in that I want to be able to flag a field to retrieve its value after commit, but not prevent me from updating that value. This could be any type of field in theory, it just happens to be a GUID in this case. I think EF is assuming that it is the only source of updates to the data.

Comment: @tensor I see, I guess I wasn't accommodating for the fact that if the ID *is* generated server side you need to re-fetch that somehow. Is there any reason why you would ever not send an ID from the client?

Comment: Yeah, this isnt the primary key as such - its some other arbritrary value. Basically if I pass a value I want that value - if I pass an empty value some magic happens (well, a trigger, so evil magic) and it is populated, but either way, I need the value back, and would like to avoid another round trip if possible. If I was in full control of the insert this would be trivial, as it is I just want a "kind of computed" attribute - but it seems I am out of luck.

Comment: @tensor yeah that sort of thing isn't supported by EF and the only way you are going to avoid a round-trip is to always generate the value client-side. Is there any reason why you can't keep it all client-side?

Comment: Unfortunatley yes, I am constrained to usign sequential guids in this case. I have another workaround possible which is slightly dirt but less of a perf problem than an insert then a select. Thanks for taking the time to help.

Answer (score 0):

When one is stuck in this kind of problems, it is often an indication that one is trying to do something *against* the architectural intentions of the framework/library being used (in this case entity framework).

The "Entity Frameworkish" way to do this is to not use a trigger at all, but rather implement the needed functionality in the entity itself.

If that's not an option, you can use the [`Refresh()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896255%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method on the `ObjectContext` to refresh the entity with the values from the database, right after the call to `SaveChanges()`.

If you are using Code First and the `DbContext` you can reach the `Refresh()` method through a cast:

```
var objCtx = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext;
objCtx.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, myEntity);
```

Answer (score 0):

If this problem was how to ensure that a field is never an empty `Guid` when it is saved then I wouldn't do it with a trigger. Wouldn't it be easier to do this in your code?

```
if (entity.GuidValue == Guid.Empty)
    entity.GuidValue = Guid.NewGuid();

context.SaveChanges();
```

If you are wed to the trigger then I think you will need to refresh the entity. Is that really a big deal?

There does appear to be a way to use a [Guid as an IDENTITY column with another IDENTITY column in the same table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12012737/150342), although I'm not sure it's quite what you want?