# Updating a table to have a unique, generated int (that is not the primary key)

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I'd like to update an existing table to have a unique, auto-generated int field. How can I do this in entity framework (code first)?

---

Longer explanation:

A client would like for each record in a table to have a unique identifier as a reference number for other databases/bookkeeping. Ordinarily I would simply use the primary key, but in this case the primary key is sensitive information (a design flaw, no doubt).

I would like to update this table to have a unique, auto-generated int that has nothing to do with the identity (I guess it's not a big deal if it does). A bonus would be if all the existing records could have values generated as well.

An alternate solution would be to change all the primary keys (and any references) in the database, but that is probably even more difficult. I'm open to alternate solutions, though.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Add `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` attribute to the property

Comment: Ah, I forgot to mention that I had tried this already. The table already has a primary key, so I get the error "Multiple identity columns specified for table 'Client'. Only one identity column per table is allowed."

Comment: Well EF doesn't support unique columns. Code first it's impossible, but you can modify the column in the database. I would go for a `DataBaseGeneratedOption.Computed`, this tells EF not to update the column itself, and then you let your database take care of it. But creating a 'unique' column through EF, nope sadly enough (still) not possible, but certainly not forbidden either.

Comment: Ok. Well thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this issue I ended up writing a script to copy everything in the table so that they were all given new ID's. I then moved any foreign keys from the original record to the copy. Then, I deleted the originals.

In this convoluted fashion I was able to alter all the ID's to something less proprietary, and could then use that ID elsewhere without worry.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing native to EF, but you can be [generate unique values for using guid's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12012736/entity-framework-code-first-using-guid-as-identity-with-another-identity-column) for property (populated using NEWID() T-SQL function).

Additionally, you could also create a new [SEQUENCE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091(v=sql.110).aspx) if your using SQL 2012+ in a similar manner in integrating a property of numeric only values.

Answer (score -1):

if u want to auto generate, auto increment is the only solution. not talking front-end. u can go for unique property.

and if u are talking about custom numbering like sku#00056, u have to go through stored procedures.

AND if u have access to frontend code, if any. go for that.